# How to make Twenty-Seventeen use two different header images for posts & front page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, image

The problem I got with the Twenty-seventeen theme is that one same image is used for the front page, where it covers the whole screen and for posts/pages, where only ~20 percent of the image is shown. It makes it impossible to make both front page and posts headers look decent. I need to separate them so front page gets one image and posts/pages get another one. Where should I be looking at to change this?

Here's header code:

```
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">

    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/header', 'image' ); ?>

    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'top' ) ) : ?>
        <div class="navigation-top">
            <div class="wrap">
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/navigation/navigation', 'top' ); ?>
                    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) : ?>
                    <nav class="social-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Footer Social Links Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'theme_location' => 'social',
                            'menu_class'     => 'social-links-menu',
                            'depth'          => 1,
                            'link_before'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">',
                            'link_after'     => '</span>' . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'chain' ) ),
                        ) );
                    ?>
                </nav><!-- .social-navigation -->
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- .wrap -->
        </div><!-- .navigation-top -->
    <?php endif; ?>

</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

Header template used in get_template_part:

```
<div class="custom-header">

    <div class="custom-header-media">
        <?php the_custom_header_markup(); ?>
    </div>

<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/site', 'branding' ); ?>
```

Comment: a. we don't know every theme on the planet, b. we really need a link to be able to understand what you are seeing c. this is purely a html\css issue. we would need to see the generated html\css not the php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to use a different photo for the front page compared to any other page just use this:

```
if (is_front_page()) {
  // Code for front-page image
} else {
  // Code for all other template pages
}
```

I think this is what you are after, however, your question could be interpreted in a lot of different ways, for example, how can I use Wordpress admin to add a different image, or what CSS should I use/how to use it to get the expected result...

Comment: So I need to change <?php the_custom_header_markup(); ?> with the code from your comment right? I believe that function creates <image> inside div. I will try it and report if I succeeded.

Comment: Yes, but you have to manually insert the image there. You can either upload an image using the Media uploader in wordpress and copy/paste the link in your code, or you can put it in an /images/ folder in your theme and use the following sample code: <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/images/YOURIMAGE.jpg">

Comment: I got it to work, now front page gets one image and the other gets another, but for some reason url gets screwed up with different slashes like this: <img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\wp/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/images/headerbg.png"> any idea why could this be happening?

Comment: Is this automatically generated code from wordpress function? The path should be relative to your locally served installation path - the expected result would be something like "http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/im‌​ages/headerbg.png". I guess it has to do with your wordpress evniroment settings or your xamp configuration settings.

Comment: It's generated by get_template_directory(), maybe I should use get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?

Comment: ...you'd probably get something similar. You either haven't setup wordpress properly - try checking if wordpress general settings use a local server based address, in your situation it should be http://localhost/wp, or try your playing with your xampp settings...

Comment: I assume you found the solution to your problem. What was it after all?

Comment: get_template_directory_uri() was the one I had to use in local enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a background image (sounds like it is), you can solve that with pure CSS. Just use

```
body {
  background-image: url('image_x.jpg');
}
```

for the regular pages and (in that order)

```
body.home {
  background-image: url('image_homepage.jpg');
}
```

for the homepage (the `.home` class is applied to the home page's `body` tag automatically)

Comment: Unfortunately, the_custom_header_markup() or something else creates <image> instead of using css for div itself..